# How to update, extend arrays by using useState in React -TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, dynamically-generated, use-state

Please help me out.
I want to add dynamically extra input fileds and save the values into textValues state.
Here is what I tried until now:

```
const [textValues, setTextValues] = useState([]);
const [numberOfTexts, setNumberOfTexts] = useState(5); <--- this value will be change dynamically
```

```
{[...Array(numberOfTexts)].map((x, i) => (
 <TextField
  style={{ marginLeft: "10px", marginTop: "10px" }}
  id="standard-basic"
  label="Text value"
  value={textValues[i]}
  onChange={(e: { target: { value: any } }) =>
  setTextValues(e.target.value)
}
/>
))}
```

So, in this case I want appear 5 input fields and in the textValues array to be 5 empty strings, than fill in step by step. I want to be able to increase and decrease the numberOfTexts, and update everything according to the number of texts. Thank you for your help!

Comment: try updating `setTextValues(e.target.value)` to `setTextValues(numberOfTexts + 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple usecase you don't need to have 2 `useState` to handle the number of fields and their values.

Usually this is a best practice to define the minimal data set model.

You can write abstract function on top of `setTextValues`, it should do the trick ;)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [textValues, setTextValues] = useState([]);

  const addField = () => {
    setTextValues(textValues.concat([""]));
  };

  const updateField = (index, newValue) => {
    const newValues = textValues.map((val, idx) => {
      if (idx === index) {
        return newValue;
      }
      return val;
    });

    setTextValues(newValues);
  };

  const removeField = () => {
    setTextValues(textValues.slice(0, textValues.length - 1));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => addField()}>Add field</button>
      <button onClick={() => removeField()}>Remove (last) field</button>
      <br />
      <div>
        {textValues.map((textValue, idx) => (
          <input
            style={{ marginLeft: "10px", marginTop: "10px" }}
            id="standard-basic"
            label="Text value"
            value={textValue}
            onChange={(e) => {
              updateField(idx, e.target.value);
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

To go further, you may want to create custom hook to abstract this logic, and have reusable chunk of state. The API may look like this:

```js
const { addField, removeField, updateField } = useInputArray(['hello', 'yo'])
```

Comment: Thank you Simon Bruneaud. It was a good solution. Because I use typescript I just needed to make some changes in the code. Like instead of  const [textValues, setTextValues] = useState([]); I wrote const [textValues, setTextValues] = useState([] as string[]);

Comment: You're welcome ;) To type a useState you must prefer using generics: `useState<string[]>([])`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this in a way that doesn't require too many changes to your code so far is to use a `useEffect()` hook to update the string array as `numberOfTexts` changes.

You could do this by adding this code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let dif = numberOfTexts - textValues.length;
  if (dif > 0) {
    setTextValues(textValues.concat(Array(dif).fill('')));
  } else if (dif < 0) {
    setTextValues(textValues.slice(0, numberOfTexts));
  }
}, [numberOfTexts]);
```

This will dynamically update the `textValues` array based on the `numberOfTexts` array.